# Find the time difference between two consecutive rows in the same table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm stuck. I've looked for an answer, but can't seem to find subtracting time in the same table from two different rows of the same table that fits. I'm having a difficult time with the following query. In the table below, I want to differentiate the TimeOut from one row to the TimeIn of the next row. Consider in the following table of finding the difference in minutes between the TimeOut in Row 1 (10:35am) and the TimeIn in Row 2 (10:38am).

Table 1: `TIMESHEET`

```
ROW    EmpID       TimeIn                   TimeOut
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       138         2014-01-05 10:04:00      2014-01-05 10:35:00   
2       138         2014-01-05 10:38:00      2014-01-05 10:59:00 
3       138         2014-01-05 11:05:00      2014-01-05 11:30:00
```

Expected results

```
ROW    EmpID       TimeIn                   TimeOut                  Minutes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       138         2014-01-05 10:04:00      2014-01-05 10:35:00       
2       138         2014-01-05 10:38:00      2014-01-05 10:59:00       3
3       138         2014-01-05 11:05:00      2014-01-05 11:30:00       6
etc
etc
etc
```

Basically, I need to differentiate the times in the query to show how long employees were on break.

I've tried doing a join, but that doesn't seem to work and I don't know if `OVER` with `PARTITION` is the way to go, because I cannot seem to follow the logic (Yeah, I'm still learning). I also considering two temp tables and comparing them, but that doesn't work when I start changing days or employee ID's. Finally, I am thinking maybe `LEAD` in an `OVER` statement? Or is it just simple to do a `DATEDIFF` with a `CAST`?

Comment: You *probably* need to lead, partition by EmpId, order by TimeIn. So something along the lines of `lead(TimeIn) over (partition by EmpId order by TimeIn)`.

Comment: I just looked up this LEAD OVER PARTITION business. That's the first compelling reason I've seen for SQL 2012 or 2014. The question is tagged sql-server-2008, possibly this ought to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this for similar problems and it need not be that the rows even be sorted:

```
select t1.EmpID, t1.TimeIn, t1.TimeOut, 
       datediff(minute, max(t2.TimeOut), t1.TimeIn) as minutes
from timesheet t1 left join timesheet t2 on t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID 
       and t2.TimeOut < t1.TimeIn
group by t1.EmpID, t1.TimeIn, t1.TimeOut
```

Let me know if this works.

Here is a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89a43/1

Comment: SS781, I am making yours as the correct answer. It provides a working query for my question and I now see why my join was not working correctly.

However, that is not to say Lashane's answer is not good. Although, I will be using your answer to solve my problem...I'll use Lashane's to learn from. Thank you for taking the time!!

Answer (score 3):

try something like that:

```
select *, DATEDIFF(minute, (
    select max(b.TimeOut)
    from TIMESHEET as b where a.EmpID=b.EmpID and b.ROW<a.ROW
    ), a.TimeIn
) as diff
from TIMESHEET as a
```

Comment: We used to use queries shaped like that but performance is heavily affected by whether the ordering value is indexed. At one point we tried using triggers on insert and update to maintain an extra column containing the result, the performance penalty for this was more predictable than occasional rebalancing of an index.

Comment: @PeterWone it is always trade off between "normalized" structure and pre-calculated fields, if you need one time report - just add index (emp,row,timeout), if you need it often - triggers is the way to go

Comment: i like this, it is like mine but looks cleaner. the performance should be similar, would you say that @Lashane ?

Comment: @SS781 I suppose group by will work slower, anyway - you can check both in sql fiddle and compare execution plans

Comment: they are very similar in performance...however i would argue my logic is better since it is independent of the presence of a row number

Comment: @SS781 ROW is a column in original table, also you can replace it with TimeIn/TimeOut - logic will be the same. as I see from execution plan - mine is faster, as there is no sorting

Comment: Lashane, thanks much. I realize that some in this thread will see yours as possibly inadequate, but it will get me where I am going. Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned PARTITION clause, given below is a version using that clause (haven't tested for syntax, but it should give you the idea)

```
;WITH EmpData AS
(
    SELECT  EmpID, 
                TimeIn, 
                TimeOut,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY TimeIn) Position
       FROM EmployeeTime 
)
SELECT a.*
         a.TimeOut-b.TimeIn OutTIme 
   FROM EmpData a  LEFT JOIN EmpData b
         ON a.EmpId = b.EmpId
      AND a.Position-1  = b.Position
```

Comment: Chandu, thank you for taking the time to answer. Your response has cleared up a  question I had regarding the OVER. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH rows AS

(

SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS rn        
FROM    TimeSheet         
)

SELECT mc.EmpID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, mc.TimeIn, mp.TimeOut) as TimeDiffInMinutes
FROM    rows mc JOIN    rows mp ON   mc.rn = mp.rn-1
```

Answer (score 0):

While looping through a cursor is normally a dismal way to do things both from a performance perspective and in terms of provability and maintainability, in cases like this, where you are traversing the edges of a directed acyclic graph, a loop can be just what the doctor ordered.

In my opinion you have two good options when using versions of SQL Server that do not support LEAD OVER PARTITION.

- loop using a cursor in T-SQL
- loop using a LINQ enumerable in application code

Whether it's worthwhile marshalling all the life-support for LINQ depends on what else you're doing.

The question is tagged sql-server-2008 which does *not* support LEAD OVER PARTITION, and on that platform in the absence of supporting indexes it is a great deal faster with a much smaller working set to use a cursor.

Comment: Why has this been voted down with no comment on why it was poorly regarded as an answer? I have addressed cases not covered by other answers and the answer is factually supportable. If there's something *wrong* with it as an answer then by all means express this with a downvote supported by a comment demonstrating your superior wisdom.